# SSRS report viewing on Google Chrome - Tablix columns growing and should not

Tags: ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

My report is a bunch of tablixes, one for each row (because the expressions are different for each row).  They are all lined up and sized exactly the same, and the textbox property for `CanGrow` are set to `False`.

All tablix Locations are x = 0.34993in

All textbox sizes are x = 0.58333in

When viewing in MS IE, it looks as it should:

[image]

Beautiful, and maybe a little sassy.

When viewing in Chrome I get this mess:

[image]

Obviously this is the worst thing to happen ever.

I'm stuck in the middle here because IT doesn't support Internet Explorer, and so SSRS report consumers have to choose between half of their screen real estate being taken up by this silliness:

[image]

Or a poorly rendered SSRS report in Chrome.

Maybe somebody can just tell me which setting is making Chrome go crazy and fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely happy with this answer, but it's definitely the best solution in terms of ease of implementation:  **IE tab for Chrome**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en-US

Display web pages using IE within Chrome. Use Java, Silverlight, ActiveX, Sharepoint, and more.

Puts an IE window inside of Chrome, answers all of my concerns.